# MacOSX XAMPP "doctrine-module"が動いてくれない

Tags: php, mysql, macos, doctrine2, zend-framework

わたしのMac愛がそれとも頑張りが足りないのでしょうか？どうもわかってくれないみたいで…助けてください。というのも…

MacOSX上にXamppを置きデータベースはMySQLを使おうとしています。言語はPHP、フレームワークはZendFramework2.5。これにcomposerでDoctrine2を入れました。

そこで、
[Zend Framework とともに Doctrine を使用する](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-doctrine-php-zend/)を参考にしてエンティティーの生成を試みました。

```
doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace=Application\Entity\ 
      --from-database annotation module\Application\src

doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" 
          --generate-methods="true" module\Application\src
```

その実行結果が

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(43): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', ’12345678909876’, Array)
#1 /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(45): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '12345678909876', Array)
#2 /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(360): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', '12345678909876', Array)
#3 /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(429): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
#4 /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(389): Doctrine\DBAL in /Users/leonardo/Development/twap/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 930
```

そしてよくある突っ込みどころのpathの情報も赤裸々に書きますと

```
echo $PATH
/Users/leonardo/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/
```

そんでもって、php.ini

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

僕の何がまちがっているのでしょうか？ぜひこの愛機と末長く仲良くやっていきたいので、もうぼくがこの子をなんと呼んでいるかとかお家の中の階層構造も赤裸々に書いてしまいました。

どうして"No such file or directory"だなんて言われてしまうのでしょうか？だれか教えていただけませんか？そしてこんなことを言われないためには、僕は次にこの子にどうしてあげれば、何をわかって上げればいいのでしょうか？

本当に困ってます。是非アドバイスを。

Answer (score 1):

PDOからMySQLに接続できないというエラーです。

Macだと標準で`/usr/bin/php`がインストールされているので、上記の`$PATH`設定ではそちらのphpが実行されるためです。

`$PATH`は、実行ファイルを検索するためのもので、記載順にファイルを探します。`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php`が実行されるようにするためには、`/usr/bin`よりも前に`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`を記載する必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。昼休憩と帰宅の電車の中で座りながら（座れるってこと）んで今PATHを削除する方法を探りながらやっております。それでふと思ったのですが、そもそもそのパスを一時的でも無効にして作業するというのはありなのでしょうか？

Comment: 野暮な質問ですみませんでした。「あり」ですよね。なんだか誰かにお作法を決めてもらう楽チンな志向が身についてしまったようで…やってみます。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます。
http://blog.hekt.org/archives/4827
↑ここにもありますが、PATHって書いた順に優先されるんですね。
基本の基本にすっかりはまってしまいました。

これで開発を進められそうです。

Comment: なるほど。どこで詰まっていたか今分かりました。回答を加筆修正してみました。これでokでしょうか?それと、PATHも変数なので一時的にどのように変更しても別に構いません。

Comment: ありがとうございました！.bash_profileに記述して動くようにし始めました:)